# Installing Beautiful Soup both on Python 2 and Python 3 in the same machine (OS X)

Tags: python, macos, beautifulsoup, pycharm

So, I had problems with installing Beautiful Soup on OS X and ended up testing several different installation methods in the Terminal. Method 1:

```
python setup.py install
```

Method 2:

```
easy_install BeautifulSoup
```

Method 3:

```
pip install BeautifulSoup
```

Finally I realized that the problem was that I was using Python 3 interpreter in PyCharm, whereas Beautiful Soup got installed on the default Python 2 interpreter that came with the OS X. Changing the interpreter to Python 2 in PyCharm made Beautiful Soup work perfectly.

Question:
How can I - with retaining the Python 2 interpreter of OS X intact - install Beautiful Soup also on the Python 3 interpreter on OS X?

Comment: You are installing BeautifulSoup version **3**, which is not compatible with Python 3. You want BeautifulSoup 4; `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: How was Python 3 installed? Does running `python3` work on the command line? What version of Python 3 is this?

Comment: Note that you can manage installations for the currently-selected interpreter (or `virtualenv`) *within PyCharm itself*. Then there's no confusion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PyCharm comes with its own [package installer](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html). Simply go to your Project Interpreter page and use the `+` button to add packages. It'll use PyPI to find packages by default.

Note that you are installing BeautifulSoup version **3**, which is not compatible with Python 3. You want BeautifulSoup 4, named [`beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4).

If `python3` works on the command line you could also just use:

```
python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Following your instructions, I installed the package directly from PyCharm (on OS X). From menu bar: PyCharm -> Preferences -> Project: […] -> Project Interpreter and then the plus sign and a search. Very convenient, it worked a charm. Many thanks, indeed.